# Map Overlays Native Android Maps Not Animating on Samsung Devices

Tags: android-maps-v2

I have Google Maps as my background map and on top of it I have weather radar TileOverlays.  The animation of these tiles is not working on all Samsung devices I've tested on (S3, S4, S5) and the Sony Xperia...but it works on all other devices I've tested on (Nexus, HTC, Motorola, and many more).  Any ideas off hand before I gather the code logic from multiple classes?

It appears that the getTileUrl I override is not being called with whatever updates are being sent out to phones lately.  Anyone heard anything of the sort?  This is the overridden method for the abstract method here:  http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/UrlTileProvider.html#getTileUrl(int, int, int)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a quote I received directly from Google:

"The workaround is to uninstall Google Play Services updates by the user, and I'm not aware of a workaround on the app developer side.

This bug was introduced with the last version of GMSCore released to the devices. On the bright side, developers are already working for a fix and we're expecting it to be released today or tomorrow."